# Static class or instance as parameter?

Tags: java

i just wanted to know whats the best solution is (The class Framework can only exist once, it holds the configuration etc)

Lets assume the following (static):

```
public class Framework {
    private Framework() {}

    private static String something;
    private static Object somethingElse;

    public static synchronized void init() {
        something = "something";
        somethingElse = new SuperFancyObject();
    }

    public static String getSomething() { return something; }
    public static Object getSomethingElse() { return somethingElse; }
}
```

Now i can use all methods inside that class anywhere by calling:

```
public void invoke(Request request, Response response) {
    ...
    Framework.getSomething();
    ...
}
```

The other solution would be:

```
public class Framework {
    private static String something;
    private static Object somethingElse;

    public Framework() {
        something = "something";
        somethingElse = new SuperFancyObject();
    }

    public String getSomething() { return something; }
    public Object getSomethingElse() { return somethingElse; }
}
```

So now, to use that, i must pass the object/class as a parameter:

```
public void invoke(Framework framework, Request request, Response response) {
    ...
    framework.getSomething();
    ...
}
```

The maybe third solution would be the static + singleton.

What i want to know now is, which is the better, more clean (maybe sexy) solution or which you prefer?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your first calling code. I assume, you want to call getSomething() on the Framework class, so you don't have to pass the framework parameter? When are you calling init() ?

Comment: Sorry... copy&paste fail

Comment: Even nicer (sexy?) would be to let an IoC container, e.g. Spring, inject the instance to everywhere necessary.

Comment: is that really sexy? i mean, i would write less code, but is the overhead worth it? (i guess it uses reflection or something)

Answer (score 2):

In many cases a singleton is preferable over static classes, since basically, a singleton is **replaceable**, and therefore more easy tot test.

Martin Fowler has written something about it :

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StaticSubstitution.html

Answer (score 0):

Go with  what's more readable. For example, if you say `Framework` can exist once, alone, then you need to make `Framework` a Singleton. This expresses directly what your program/object should do.

Don't think of sexiness, think of communication. For example, you would be really angry if I spoke to you in 15th Century English. Wouldn't thee be shovelled?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your class:

```
public class Framework {

    private String something;

    /** Singleton instance */
    private static Framework iSingleton = new Framework();     // SINGLETON

    protected Framework(){
          //init
     }

    public static String getSomething() {
         return iSingleton.something;
    }
}
```

In your invoke method, I don't need framework instance. 
You can call this:

```
public void invoke(Framework framework, Request request, Response response) {

    Framework.getSomething();   //Call static method.
}
```

Comment: Ye, simple singleton, like i said in the post as a third solution. I would write it as a LazySingleton instead, so the class will be created only if and when needed

Answer (score -1):

If it has state, make sure does not use and is not accessible from statics.